# MVC Intellisense

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, visual-studio, intellisense

Dont have any intellisense when creating a sample MVC3 app.

[image]

Config files are fine, project compiles and works as it should when ran...

Have MVC3 & MVC4 installed, same thing with each.

Have VS2010 & VS11 installed (running fine side by side), same thing here... no intellisense.

Errors:
'ViewData' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
'Url' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
'Partial' is not a member of 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper'.
'ActionLink' is not a member of 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper'.

The 'ActionLink' error should be trageting the Mvc library should it not?

Comment: Nope, have updated Q with the error replies...

Comment: Have you restarted VS?  Sometimes I'll randomly lose IntelliSense and a restart usually takes care of it.

Comment: Restarted PC & resest settings in Import And Export tool... still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't worry. its a reported issue with visual studio. In the latest upgrade its not there. Me also was facing the same issue.